# Monitor data set if results are ok

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have a accommodations index with 2000 properties.  I want to automate queries and if results are lower then value X then we show this in a table in kibana.   So we know that we must take action.

Example search type villa, tuscany has 430 results.  I must be sure is 430 and check this 4 times per 24 hour.

remco

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Elasticsearch transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-overview.html) feature for that. You can schedule trigger time (4 hours) and it will index the search results into elasticsearch, `eg. villa-tuscany has 430 hits`. After than you can check every 24 hours and compare the results for 4 hours periods.
[image]